# Outlook plug-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I'm looking build an outlook addin that can do the following. Would like to hear tips from anyone who might have done this before.

- Upon install, read the person's profile in outlook and call a service which will create an account for that person in my app
- When person sends an email from outlook with a .pptx/.ppt file(s) attached, it calls a service to automatically upload that file(s) into my app.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? What have you tried? Is that COM or a JS addin?

Answer (score 0):

> Upon install, read the person's profile in outlook and call a service which will create an account for that person in my app

You can use [Namespace.CurrentProfileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-currentprofilename-property-outlook) property introduced with Outlook 2007.

> When person sends an email from outlook with a .pptx/.ppt file(s) attached, it calls a service to automatically upload that file(s) into my app.

The [Application.ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-itemsend-event-outlook) event is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem , is used. So, in the event handler you can check the Attachments collection for the files specified and do your web calls.

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly.